# how to Vlookup a value on a worksheet not present on the first column?

Tags: excel-formula

I have seen that VLOOKUP excel formula looks for a value on the first column of an another worksheet.

How can I achieve a similar search of a value which is not on the first column.
Lets have a worksheet1 with values as follows:

```
xx value1 index1 yy
xx value2 index2 yy
xx value3 index3 yy
```

I would like to fetch the value3 by searching for "index3" on another worksheet.
I will appreciate if someone can write the required excel formula.

Comment: Probably belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=INDEX(Table1!B:B,MATCH("index3",Table1!C:C,0))
```